# Saving checkbox state for dynamically created checkboxes in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I have created the listview which consists of all the application installed on that device. 
When the installed applications are displayed to the user, each application have its corresponding checkbox.
User clicks on the multiple checkboxes and the corresponding application names are saved.

What I want is, when user again starts the application, the checkboxes of the applications which are saved by user should be checked.

How can I do this ? Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

AppList.java

```
public class AppList extends Activity {
AppInfoAdapter adapter ;
AppInfo app_info[] ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_list);
    final ListView listApplication = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listApplication);
    final Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button001);
    final Context context = null;
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<app_info.length;i++)
            {
                if(adapter.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {

                                   result.append(app_info[i].applicationName).append(",");
                   // result.append(",");
                }

            }

            String playlists = result.toString();
            StoringClas.writeApps(AppList.this, playlists);
            //String[] po = playlists.split(",");
            //b.setText(po[2]+"o");

        }

    });

    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getApplicationInfo();
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> pInfo = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
    pInfo.addAll(pm.getInstalledPackages(0));
    app_info = new AppInfo[pInfo.size()];

    int counter = 0;
    for(PackageInfo item: pInfo){
        try{

            applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(item.packageName, 1);

                     app_info[counter] = new AppInfo(pm.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo), 
                             String.valueOf(pm.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo)));


            System.out.println(counter);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        counter++;
    }

   adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, R.layout.item_row, app_info);
    listApplication.setAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

AppInfoAdapter.java

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppInfo> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates; 

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
AppInfo  data[] = null;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, AppInfo[] data){
    super(context, layoutResourceId,data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(data.length);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View row = convertView;
    AppInfoHolder holder= null;

    if (row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new AppInfoHolder();

        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView001);
        holder.chkSelect = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        row.setTag(holder);

    }
    else{
        holder = (AppInfoHolder)row.getTag();
    }


    AppInfo appinfo = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(appinfo.applicationName);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(appinfo.icon);
   // holder.chkSelect.setChecked(true);
   // data[2].applicationName="kj";
  /*   String mm=StoringClas.readApps(context);
   String[] po= mm.split(",");
    for(int k=0;k<po.length;k++){
        for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++){
        if(po[k].contains(data[j].applicationName))
        {
            holder.chkSelect.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, true));
        }

    }}*/



    holder.chkSelect.setTag(position);
    holder.chkSelect.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
    holder.chkSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    return row;

}
public boolean isChecked(int position) {
    return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
}

public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
    mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

}

public void toggle(int position) {
    setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
        boolean isChecked) {

     mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);    

}
static class AppInfoHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    CheckBox chkSelect;}}
```

AppInfo.java

```
public class AppInfo {
public Drawable icon;
public String applicationName;

public AppInfo(){
    super();
}

public AppInfo(Drawable icon, String applicationName){
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.applicationName = applicationName;
}}
```

Comment: Google for SharedPreferences android

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways in Android to save information between app launches. The Android website provides a great overview of the different built-in ways: [Saving Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)

Once you choose a way to save, like `SharedPreference` or database, then when your app is launched, you can check the saved information and display that to the user.